# Hide/show gridview column based on role

Tags: c#, asp.net

Want to be able to set an "Edit" linkbutton to visible=false unless the user has a role of "Editor".

Been poking around stackoverflow and elsewhere and so far have not been able to get this to work.

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Questions Awaiting Review" AllowSorting="True" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" CaptionAlign="Top" EmptyDataText="No Questions Pending Review." 
    PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerStyle-Font-Size="Large" DataKeyNames="QuestionID"
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#cccccc"
    OnPreRender="GridView1_OnPreRender">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="QuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyObjective" HeaderText="Key Objective" ItemStyle-Width="250" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" HeaderText="Submitted Date" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Details" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' runat="server" CommandName="viewQuestion">View Question</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' runat="server" CommandName="editQuestion">Edit Question</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Have changed the code behind to use OnPreRender for the gridview, which if the value is hardcoded hides the column. However when I try to retrieve the is in role of editor then the value does not seem to be evaluating correctly. Always returns false even when the user has a role of Editor.

```
protected void GridView1_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Editor"))
        {
            // Enter correct column index.
            GridView1.Columns[4].Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Hoping I'm missing something simple, new to asp.net so not unlikely.

Comment: The code above is now working, not sure what changed so that it is evaluating correctly, but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show/hide an entire column instead of ***LinkButton*** control. Otherwise, ***unauthorized user will always see a column with blank cells*** which is odd.

The following example will hide an entire column.

### Screen Shot (Authorize vs Unauthorized)

[image]

### ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
            runat="server"
            DataKeyNames="QuestionID"
            OnPreRender="GridView1_OnPreRender"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyObjective" HeaderText="Key Objective" ItemStyle-Width="250" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>'
                            runat="server" CommandName="editQuestion">Edit Question</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string KeyObjective { get; set; }
}

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = new List<Question>
            {
                new Question {QuestionID = 1, KeyObjective = "One"},
                new Question {QuestionID = 2, KeyObjective = "Two"},
                new Question {QuestionID = 3, KeyObjective = "Three"},
            };
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isEditor = true; // Business logic here
        if (isEditor)
        {
            // Enter correct column index.
            GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Like the process you have outlined here and agree that having the column completely removed is better than a gaping hole. Not sure what to put into the "Business log here area to check if the logged in user is a member of the role "Editor" however.

Comment: have added this to the code behind: protected void GridView1_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(Roles.IsUserInRole("Editor"))
            {
                // Enter correct column index.
                GridView1.Columns[4].Visible = true;
            }
           else
            {
                GridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
            }      However now I get an error saying that role management is not enabled. Checked the Nuget packages and the Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Core package is installed. Not sure how to enable this in web.config.

Comment: No, I get an error saying:  An exception of type 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.

Comment: ***role management is not enabled*** - Error message is totally different from original question. Could you please create a new question with the necessary code so that we can look at it?

Comment: Looks like I have the role management issue taken care of (no more errors), however the column is staying hidden even if the user is a member of the Editor role

Comment: About code is pretty straight forward; ***I have tested it***. If it doesn't work in your application, you want to create a new ***ASPX*** page without master page, copy my answer, and toggle ***isEditor*** with ***true*** or ***false***. Other than that, you will have to set a break point in your code, and work on your business logic.

Comment: What I guess I don't understand is how does the Bool isEditor know to go look for the role of editor? I replaced that with an IF statement for checking for editor, and is not working, but the bool as you wrote it doesn't appear to have any logic to check if the user is in the editor role??? What am I missing?

Comment: I obviously cannot answer the rest of the problems; I do not know how your application work. It might be that `Roles.IsUserInRole("Editor")` does not work at all. ***As I said, you need to create a new question regarding Role Provider***.

Comment: Not sure why but this morning the code started being evaluating the role correctly. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Hide last column.

```
this.GridView1.Columns[this.GridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("Editor");
```

Comment: After the this.GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Does not have to happen after data binding. Columns do not depend on data being there, unlike rows. So anywhere after Page_Init is fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the LinkButton like this, with the `Visibility` property set from a function in code behind.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" Visible='<%# ShowEditBasedOnRole() %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' runat="server" CommandName="editQuestion">Edit Question</asp:LinkButton>
```

And then in code behind the function that returns a `bool`

```
public bool ShowEditBasedOnRole()
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Editor"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also very nice solution, perhaps even better then manipulating columns. The only issue here is that column will be still visible, even though empty

Comment: Simplified:  `return Roles.IsUserInRole("Editor");`  No `if`/`else` required.

Comment: @Andrei, You're right, missed that part. I used the first sentence as my guideline (`set an "Edit" linkbutton to visible=false unless..`), not the title

Answer (score 0):

One quick modification instead of accessing the column by index. it can be accessed using header text which would not affect the code even if new column is inserted before the accessed column in future the code snippet

```
protected void grdResults_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TemplateField FieldToAccess= grdResults.Columns.OfType<TemplateField> 
                                 ().Where(f => f.HeaderText == 
                                 "ValidityDate").FirstOrDefault();
    if (role)
    FieldToAccess.Visible = false;
}
```